# tkinter , unexpected behaviour of after,callback

Tags: tkinter

This function displays an image in a frame and rotates it incrementally from stated start and end points. It works in the sense that the image displays at the correct  end angle and the while loop is incrementing. Print output:

```
angle is 8  card angle is 32
2
angle is 12  card angle is 32
3
angle is 16  card angle is 32
4
angle is 20  card angle is 32
5
angle is 24  card angle is 32
6
angle is 28  card angle is 32
7
angle is 32  card angle is 32
8
```

What the function does not do is to pause at each increment to display intermediate rotated images as I expected  'after' to do. The script which calls this function uses 'after' successfully on the same widget so I am guessing that while is not doing what I think.  I have tried a number of ways of looping with the same result or complicated tracebacks about tcl commands. What am I missing please?

```
    def turn( self):
        while True:
            if self.angle > self.card_angle:
                break

            print(f'angle is {self.angle }  card angle is {self.card_angle}')

            self.angle+=4

            self.label.destroy()

            #create PIL ImageTk which has a rotate method.
            self.tkimage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.card_pic.rotate(self.angle,expand=1))

            #creat label with tkImage and show label
            self.label=tk.Label(self)   
            self.label['image']=self.tkimage        
            self.label.pack()           

            self.count+=1
            print(self.count)
            self.label.after(1000,self.turn)
```

Comment: please fix the formatting of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. Nothing to do with tkinter, just my persistent inability to understand while loops. It works fine with 'if' + return.